# Usage of 'Allow' in robots.txt

Tags: seo, web-crawler, robots.txt, googlebot

Recently I saw a site's robots.txt as follows:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /login
Allow: /register
```

I could find only `Allow` entries and no `Disallow` entries.

From [this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en), I could understand robots.txt is nearly a blacklist file to `Disallow` pages to be crawled. So, `Allow` is used only to allow a sub part of domain which is already blocked with `Disallow`. Similar to this:

```
Allow: /crawlthis
Disallow: /
```

But, that robots.txt has no `Disallow` entries. So, does this robots.txt let Google crawl all the pages? Or, does it allow only the specified pages tagged with `Allow`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that this robots.txt file allows Google to crawl all the pages on the website. A thorough guide can be found here: http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html.

If you want googleBot to only be allowed to crawl the specified pages then correct format would be:

```
User Agent:*
Disallow:/
Allow: /login
Allow: /register
```

(I would normally disallow those specific pages though as they don't provide much value to searchers.)

It's important to note that the Allow command line only works with some robots (including Googlebot)

Comment: (The official standard only mentions "User-Agent" and "Disallow". "*" and "$" don't officially have any special meaning in Disallow directives either.)

Answer (score 2):

There is no point in having a robots.txt record that has `Allow` lines but no `Disallow` lines. Everything is allowed to be crawled by default anyway.

According to the [original robots.txt specification](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html) (which doesn’t define `Allow`), it’s even invalid, as at least one `Disallow` line is required (bold emphasis mine):

> The record starts with one or more `User-agent` lines, followed by **one or more** `Disallow` lines […]

> **At least one** `Disallow` field needs to be present in a record.

---

In other words, a record like

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /login
Allow: /register
```

is equivalent to the record

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

i.e., everything is allowed to be crawled, including (but not limited to) URLs with paths that start with `/login` and `/register`.